# expandable buttons on hover aligned to the right side of screen, how to keep the not hovered buttons aligned right?

Tags: css

I have a working code, which expands the buttons on a map when user hover over. My problem is  when user hover over a button on the right side it moves all the other buttons as well. I am not sure what am I missing. Here you can see the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/qjwtum3c/2/

```
    .extendable-button-container-right {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px; /* Adjust top position */
      right: 20px;
      z-index: 1000;
    }


    .extendable-button-right {
      background-color: #0d6efd;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Add shadow effect */
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
   
    }

    .extendable-button-right i {
      color: white; /* Change icon color to white */
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .extendable-button-right:hover,
    .extendable-button-right:focus {
      background-color: #0d6efd;
    }

    .extendable-button-right:active {
      background-color: #0daafd;
    }

    .hint-right {
      display: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: white; /* Change hint text color to white */
      margin-right: 5px;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      padding-right: 5px
    }

    .extendable-button-right:hover .hint-right,
    .extendable-button-right:focus .hint-right {
      display: block;
    }

    .extendable-button-right:hover i,
    .extendable-button-right:focus i {
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }
```

Comment: I got an improvement here: https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/vqryuftw/9/ 

Comment: Another "improvement" https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/vqryuftw/13/ 

Comment: you first code is working fine, just remove flex-direction: row-reverse;

Comment: but I still need to check what did you change, however I could accept as answer

Comment: In the first Fiddle I put `direction:rtl` at `.extendable-button-container-right` into it. Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the items are on the right side, I changed the `direction` to `direction:rtl`.

```
.extendable-button-container-right {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px; /* Adjust top position */
      right: 20px;
      z-index: 1000;
      direction: rtl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make them `float: right;` and between them have a `div` with `clear:both`:

```css
    #map {
      height: 400px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .extendable-button-container-left {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px; /* Adjust top position */
      left: 20px;
      z-index: 1000;
    }

    .extendable-button-container-right {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px; /* Adjust top position */
      right: 20px;
      z-index: 1000;
    }

    .extendable-button-left {
      background-color: #0d6efd;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Add shadow effect */
    }

    .extendable-button-left i {
      color: white; /* Change icon color to white */
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .extendable-button-left:hover,
    .extendable-button-left:focus {
      background-color: #0d6efd;
    }

    .extendable-button-left:active {
      background-color: #0daafd;
    }

    .hint-left {
      display: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: white; /* Change hint text color to white */
      margin-left: 10px;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .extendable-button-left:hover .hint-left,
    .extendable-button-left:focus .hint-left {
      display: block;
    }

    .extendable-button-left:hover i,
    .extendable-button-left:focus i {
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    .extendable-button-right {
      background-color: #0d6efd;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Add shadow effect */
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
   
    }

    .extendable-button-right i {
      color: white; /* Change icon color to white */
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .extendable-button-right:hover,
    .extendable-button-right:focus {
      background-color: #0d6efd;
    }

    .extendable-button-right:active {
      background-color: #0daafd;
    }

    .hint-right {
      display: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: white; /* Change hint text color to white */
      margin-right: 5px;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      padding-right: 5px
    }

    .extendable-button-right:hover .hint-right,
    .extendable-button-right:focus .hint-right {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .extendable-button-right {
        float: right;
    }

    .extendable-button-right:hover i,
    .extendable-button-right:focus i {
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Leaflet Map with Buttons</title>
  <!-- Leaflet CSS and JS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<div class="extendable-button-container-left">
  <!-- Button 1 -->
  <button class="extendable-button-left" onclick="zoomToBudapest()">
    <i class="fas fa-square"></i>
    <span class="hint-left">Zoom to Budapest</span>
  </button>

  <!-- Button 2 -->
  <button class="extendable-button-left" onclick="zoomToLondon()">
    <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
    <span class="hint-left">Zoom to London</span>
  </button>

  <!-- Button 3 -->
  <button class="extendable-button-left" onclick="zoomToNewYork()">
    <i class="fas fa-globe"></i>
    <span class="hint-left">Zoom to New York</span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="extendable-button-container-right">
  <!-- Button 4 -->
  <button class="extendable-button-right" onclick="zoomToParis()">
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <span class="hint-right">Zoom to Paris</span>
  </button>
  
  <div style="clear:both"></div>

  <!-- Button 5 -->
  <button class="extendable-button-right" onclick="zoomToRome()">
    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
    <span class="hint-right">Zoom to Rome</span>
  </button>

  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  
  <!-- Button 6 -->
  <button class="extendable-button-right" onclick="zoomToBerlin()">
    <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
    <span class="hint-right">Zoom to Berlin</span>
  </button>
</div>

<script>
  // Initialize Leaflet map
  var map = L.map('map', {
    zoomControl: false // Disable default zoom control
  }).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

  // Add base tile layer
  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);

  // Function to zoom to Budapest
  function zoomToBudapest() {
    map.setView([47.4979, 19.0402], 13);
  }

  // Function to zoom to London
  function zoomToLondon() {
    map.setView([51.5074, -0.1278], 13);
  }

  // Function to zoom to New York
  function zoomToNewYork() {
    map.setView([40.7128, -74.0060], 13);
  }

  // Function to zoom to Paris
  function zoomToParis() {
    map.setView([48.8566, 2.3522], 13);
  }

  // Function to zoom to Rome
  function zoomToRome() {
    map.setView([41.9028, 12.4964], 13);
  }

  // Function to zoom to Berlin
  function zoomToBerlin() {
    map.setView([52.5200, 13.4050], 13);
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some rather complicated code to read.
The `C` of `CSS` stands for Cascading, in other words: there is no need to multiply class declarations on sub-elements.

Here's a way to code for this:

```js
const coord =
  { Budapest : [47.4979,  19.0402]
  , London   : [51.5074,  -0.1278]
  , NewYork  : [40.7128, -74.0060]
  , Paris    : [48.8566,   2.3522]
  , Rome     : [41.9028,  12.4964]
  , Berlin   : [52.5200,  13.4050]
  };

// Initialize Leaflet map  ---Disable default zoom control
const map = L.map('map', { zoomControl: false }).setView( coord.London, 13);

// Add base tile layer
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

document.querySelectorAll('.extendable-button-container button[data-coord]')
.forEach( btn => btn.onclick =()=>
  {
  map.setView( coord[btn.dataset.coord], 13);
  })
```

```css
#map {
  height   : 400px;
  }
.extendable-button-container {
  position : absolute;
  top      : 20px; 
  z-index  : 1000;
  }
.extendable-button-container.on_left {
  left     : 20px;  
  }
.extendable-button-container.on_right {
  right     : 20px;
  }
.extendable-button-container button {
  display          : block;
  background-color : #0d6efd;
  color            : white;
  padding          : 10px;
  border           : none;
  border-radius    : 4px;
  cursor           : pointer;
  transition       : all 0.3s ease;
  margin-bottom    : 10px;
  box-shadow       : 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size        : 14px;
  }
.extendable-button-container.on_right button {
  clear     : both;
  float     : right;
  direction : rtl;
  }
.extendable-button-container button:hover i.fas {
  display   : inline-block;
  }
.extendable-button-container button span {
  display        : inline-block;
  width          : 0;
  height         : 0;
  overflow       : hidden;
  vertical-align : bottom;
  color          : white; 
  margin         : 0;
  text-shadow    : 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
.extendable-button-container button:hover span ,
.extendable-button-container button:focus span {
  width  : auto;
  height : auto;
  margin : 0 10px;
  }
 
.extendable-button-container button:hover i.fas ,
.extendable-button-container button:focus i.fas {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" />

<div id="map"></div>

<div class="extendable-button-container on_left">
  <button data-coord="Budapest">
    <i class="fas fa-square"></i><span>Zoom to Budapest</span>
  </button>
  <button data-coord="London">
    <i class="fas fa-circle"></i><span>Zoom to London</span>
  </button>
  <button data-coord="NewYork">
    <i class="fas fa-globe"></i><span>Zoom to New York</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="extendable-button-container on_right">
  <button data-coord="Paris">
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i><span>Zoom to Paris</span>
  </button>
  <button data-coord="Rome">
    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i><span>Zoom to Rome</span>
  </button>
  <button data-coord="Berlin">
    <i class="fas fa-moon"></i><span>Zoom to Berlin</span>
  </button>
</div>
```